# How to change the name of an xml element globally across the whole project

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have some string elements in the strings.xml file of my android project and I want to change their name in the strings.xml file and everywhere else where they were used.

Is there a way to do this in android studio without having to go through each file manually to edit the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click the name in 'strings.xml'
- Select 'Refactor' option
- Select 'Rename' option
- Edit the name and hit 'Refactor'

Answer (score 1):

As a shortcut, you can change the name of an `XML` element, this way:

- Select the `XML`'s name (or `XML`'s file in the left panel),
- press `SHIFT+F6` (or `FN+SHIFT+F6` on MacOS),
- change the name (in the opened box),
- click `refactor`.